# Perl Excel parser truncating columns

Tags: perl, excel, file

I am new to Perl and trying to decode a Perl script which reads an Excel file and export the data into a text file. One of the steps in the script is performing weirdly.
This is the step:

```
@array_name = grep {$_} @array_name;
```

This step just truncates the last column if the value is `0`; otherwise it works properly. If I remove this step, the last column with value `0` is back, but it includes some dummy `NULL` columns in my extract which are not part of my source Excel file.

Can someone please help me understand this step?

Answer (score 1):

The grep command filters non empty content. So everything that does not evaluate as true will be discarded. Empty cells and cells containing `0` will be removed. If you just want to remove empty cells you could use

```
@array_name = grep { defined && length } @array_name ;
```

instead.

Comment: Hi dgw, i am facing one more issue when i include this line it removes columns with blank values. I need these columns in my final output.please suggest

Comment: @user1415006 Then just make it `@array_name = grep { defined } @array_name ;` this just removes undef values.

Comment: If i do that...it then it keeps the column with the blank value but strangely includes two more empty columns which are NOT part of my excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
$A->[$i][10]=~s/\n//g;

$variable_value =~s/\n//g;
```

`$variable_value` is the variable in which the value is stored.

It will remove the next line.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` basically returns all true values from the array, and 0 is interpolated as false.

For example `grep` is used here to filter true values into @b,

```
my @dirty = (0,1,2,3,,0,5,);
my @clean = grep {$_} @dirty;
for(@clean) {print "$_\n";}
```

Returns

```
1
2
3
5
```

A little trick for preserving the zeros involves adding a newline to the grep argument:

```
my @dirty = (0,1,2,3,,0,5,);
my @clean = grep {"$_\n"} @dirty;
for(@clean) {print "$_\n";}
```

Which returns,

```
0
1
2
3
0
5
```